# css using float: right with vertical-align: middle

Tags: html, css, position

I have 2 divs (in a wrapper) that I am using to display a photograph and the title of the photograph side by side and vertical-align as middle.

The issue that I am having is that when I attempt to float the photograph to the right and float the title to the left, the title and photograph are no longer vertical-aligned as middle.

It seems that when I use float, the vertical-align becomes top.

**How do I add the floats and keep the vertical-align as middle?** I have spent 2 hours trying all I know. I hope someone can point out what I have done wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="live_preview_top_header_wrapper">

    <div class="live_preview_top_header_title">Title</div>

    <div class="live_preview_top_header_photograph">

        <img id="id_name_details_photograph_01_live_preview" src="{{ name_details_photograph_url }}" />

    </div>

</div>


.live_preview_top_header_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffaaaa;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.live_preview_top_header_title {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #aaaaff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.live_preview_top_header_photograph {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #cc0033;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You want vertical middle of screen or middle of div?

Comment: ketan, vertical middle of div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try centering with Line-Height in the parent Div, and using vertical-align: middle; on the content eg image and title.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xb5gwvuu/)

```
.live_preview_top_header_wrapper {
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffaaaa;
line-height: 200px;
}  

.live_preview_top_header_wrapper {
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffaaaa;
line-height: 200px;
}

.live_preview_top_header_photograph {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #cc0033;
 float: right;
 line-height: 200px;
}

.live_preview_top_header_photograph img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```